# Change color and background behind text of all 'description' environments

Tags: color, environments

I'm new with LaTeX and like to change some parameters of the `description` environment throughout the document.
As minimum, I like to have two arguments: color of text of item and background-color behind text as description.

In other words, I want to give style.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I took the liberty to reformat and rephrase your question a little, so that it looks better. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not change the style of environments as easy as it is possible using CSS with HTML. However, you can redefine `description` or define your own variant which adds the color commands.

To set the background color you can use my [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newenvironment{cdescription}{%
  \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth,bgcolor=blue,vspace=\smallskipamount}
    \begin{description}
      \color{red}%
}{%
    \end{description}
  \end{adjustbox}
}

\begin{document}

Text before

\begin{cdescription}
    \item[Hello] World
    \item[Example] Item
\end{cdescription}

text after

\end{document}
```

---

If you want to redefine `description` instead you can save the old definition away and use it internally.

```
\let\olddescription\description
\let\endolddescription\enddescription
\renewenvironment{description}{%
  \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth,bgcolor=blue,vspace=\smallskipamount}
    \begin{olddescription}
      \color{red}%
}{%
    \end{olddescription}
  \end{adjustbox}
}
```

---

If you want to set the colors for every environment simply add `[2]` after the environment name (e.g., `\newenvironment{cdescription}[2]{%`) and replace the color names with `#1` and `#2` in the definition.

Comment: thx you very mach

\renewenvironment is very useful

Answer (score 2):

The `description` environment itself does not have options for color; however, there are standard constructions you can use to get color.  For example, if you want just the two things you mentioned, you can use the `xcolor` package and the following commands:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\colorbox{blue}{%
 \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
  \begin{description}
   \color{red}
    \item[First] Some text
    \item[Second] Some more text
  \end{description}%
 \end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

This has a few parts:

- To get the background color *just* for the `description` itself, I put it in a `\colorbox`.
- However, a paragraph-constructing environment like `description` must be in a page-like setting, which `\colorbox` is not, so I further embed it in a `minipage` whose width is that of the text.
- To get the text color, I issue `\color{red}` just inside the `description`.  Every environment is a group and shields the exterior from changes made in its contents, so the color won't continue outside the description itself.

You say you also want to make these changes throughout the document, to every `description`.  For that, you can define a command that encapsulates this:

```
% #2 is background color, #3 is text color
% Optional #1 is width
% #4 is the contents of the description
\newcommand\colordesc[4][\textwidth]{%
 \noindent
 \colorbox{#2}{%
  \begin{minipage}{#1}%
   \begin{description}
    \color{#3} 
    #4
   \end{description}%
  \end{minipage}%
 }%
}

% Use like:
\colordesc[5in]{blue}{red}{
 \item[First] some text
 \item[Second] some more text
}
```

(I made this a command rather than an environment because it is irritating to split the braces of a `\colorbox` across the ends of an environment.)

Comment: The `lrbox` environment was created for this kind of things.

Comment: @egreg: Ah, now I know what that environment does. :)

Answer (score 2):

At the moment all provided answers can't break across pages. There are some packages which can handle page breaks as well. The most common are

- [`framed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed)
- [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed)
- [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)

For a simple background can be achieved with `framed`. If you want to draw a more power full frame you may use `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`. Instead of redefining all description environments I recommend to provide an new environment. If you redefine all description environments the following solutions don't work well.

To setup the new description environment I am using the package `enumitem`.

### `framed`

The package `framed` defines the environment `shaded`. To use the environment you have to declare the `shadecolor` first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\newlist{cdescription}{description}{1}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.95}%color of the background
\setlist[cdescription,1]{before=\begin{shaded},after=\end{shaded}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{cdescription}
\item[first lipsum] \lipsum[1]
\item[second lipsum] \lipsum[2]
\item[third lipsum] \lipsum[3]
\item[fourth lipsum] \lipsum[4]
\item[fifth lipsum] \lipsum[5]
\end{cdescription}
\end{document}
```

### `mdframed`

The package `mdframed` provide his own command to surround any environment. This is done by `\surroundwithmdframed`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\newlist{cdescription}{description}{1}
\mdfdefinestyle{cdescription}{%
  hidealllines=true,%no lines drawn
  backgroundcolor=gray!15,
  skipabove=\topskip,
  skipbelow=\topskip,
  roundcorner=15pt,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=cdescription]{cdescription}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{cdescription}
\item[first lipsum] \lipsum[1]
\item[second lipsum] \lipsum[2]
\item[third lipsum] \lipsum[3]
\item[fourth lipsum] \lipsum[4]
\item[fifth lipsum] \lipsum[5]
\end{cdescription}
\end{document}
```

### `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\newlist{cdescription}{description}{1}
\setlist[cdescription,1]{before={\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,boxrule=0pt]},after=\end{tcolorbox}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{cdescription}
\item[first lipsum] \lipsum[1]
\item[second lipsum] \lipsum[2]
\item[third lipsum] \lipsum[3]
\item[fourth lipsum] \lipsum[4]
\item[fifth lipsum] \lipsum[5]
\end{cdescription}
\end{document}
```