# change style of all same objects in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change color and background behind text of all 'description' environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63030/change-color-and-background-behind-text-of-all-description-environments)

How I can change style of all same objects in document?
For example, `\description {}`

I'm a newbee in LaTeX, so I don't know how I can make style for all document, as css in web

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more, what exactly it is you would like to change?

Comment: @sloede, color of text and the background color behind the text.
I cant use \colorbox, because I generate pdf with template. 
And I cant use \colorbox because I generate pdf from markdown.

I want get as same as 
p { color:red; background-color:black}

<p>qqq</p>